# Unable to use Ant design's Drawer in react app

Tags: reactjs, antd, drawer

I am trying to incorporate Ant Design's `Drawer` component in my React App but for some reason I can't get the Drawer to open or even appear in the source code upon inspecting the page. I am able to use it in another project and I noticed in the `package.json` file for the other project I had `"antd": "^4.2.5"` whereas in my current `package.json` I had `"antd": "^4.3.2"`. However, upon changing the version I ran into the same issue. Then I literally just copied the code from the other project into my current one to no avail. I have deleted `node_modules`, I re-ran `npm install`, At this point I am just trying to render the basic `Drawer` example provided by Ant Design but it's not rendering at all.

Here is my `package.json` file.

```
{
  "name": "my-app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^4.2.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^9.3.2",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^7.1.2",
    "antd": "^4.3.2",
    "react": "^16.13.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.13.1",
    "react-scripts": "3.4.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

And here is my `App` Component. I also removed any reference to other components and style sheets aside from Ant Design's CSS.

```
import React from 'react';
import {Drawer} from 'antd';
import "antd/dist/antd.css";

function App() {

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Drawer
        title="Basic Drawer"
        placement="right"
        closable={false}
        onClose={()=>console.log('bruh')}
        visible={true}
      >
        <p>Some contents...</p>
        <p>Some contents...</p>
        <p>Some contents...</p>
      </Drawer>
      <h1>React App</h1>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

I can incorporate something else in the meantime but I am at a loss as to why it isn't rendering. I am also getting no errors in the console or in my terminal.

Comment: I faced this issue in `antd version 4.21.4`. I tried the solution by @DennisVash but it didn't work. Upgrading antd to the `latest version (4.23.6)` fixed it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's surely a bug in `antd` right now (version `4.3.2`), to fix it just use `getContainer={false}` or specify the `container` to which render the drawer.

```
<Drawer
  title="Basic Drawer"
  placement="right"
  closable={false}
  onClose={() => console.log("bruh")}
  getContainer={false}
  visible={true}
>...</Drawer>
```

[image: Edit weathered-cloud-36fi4]

Comment: That worked perfectly thank you. I'm having trouble with fixed positioning of other elements too I wonder it's connected to the antd bug. SO won't let me accept the answer yet but I will in a few mins

Comment: Ask a new question and explain the issue (try recreating in codesandbox).

Comment: SO just says I have to wait 2 mins before accepting I don't think it's an issue with the OP or answer.

Comment: OMG, you helped me alots. So appriciated.